# Question about implicit differentiation in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, implicit-differentiation

I was wondering what was incorrect about this procedure that seems to lead to a contradiction. In polar coordinates its true that:

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

If I differentiate the equation implicitly with respect to $x$ I get the following:

$2x = 2r\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \implies \frac{x}{r} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x},$

which finally yields:

$\frac{r\cos \theta}{r} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \implies \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \cos \theta.$

However, if I differentiate $r$ with respect to $x$ from the definition of $x$ in polar coordinates, I get a different result:

$x = r\cos\theta \implies r = \frac{x}{\cos\theta} \implies \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}.$

Comment: You did $\frac{dr}{dx} y^2=0$ when $y=r\sin(\theta)$? [Very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064074/implicitly-differentiating-polar-equations)

Comment: @TymaGaidash I precisely thought about that, Now I replaced $y$ in $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and differentiating now yields the correct result. Just wanted to see if there were other points of view about this. Thanks for your response.