# $\frac{d}{d\theta}\mu=?$, where $\theta=\log\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}$

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

How can I solve the following differentiation :

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\mu,$$

where $\theta=\log\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\dfrac{dy}{dx}\cdot\dfrac{dx}{dy}=1,$  **See** [Is $ \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{\mathrm{d}{y}} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}{y}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} \right)} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292590/is-frac-mathrmdx-mathrmdy-frac1-left-frac-mathrmdy)

$\dfrac{d\mu}{d\theta}=\dfrac1{\dfrac{d\theta}{d\mu}}$

Now $\dfrac{d\theta}{d\mu}=\dfrac{d(\ln\mu)}{d\mu}-\dfrac{d\{\ln(1-\mu)\}}{d\mu}=?$

Answer (score 1):

You will need the expression of $\mu$ in terms of $\theta$, when what you have is $\theta$ in terms of $\mu$

Since
$$
\theta = \log{\frac{\mu}{1 - \mu}} \\
e^\theta = \frac{\mu}{1 - \mu} \\
e^\theta(1 - \mu) = \mu \\
e^\theta = \mu(1 + e^\theta) \\
\mu = \frac{e^\theta}{1 + e^\theta}
$$

Now, differentiate $\mu$ using the chain rule, that

$$
\frac{d\mu}{d\theta} = \frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{e^\theta}{1 + e^\theta} = \\
e^\theta \frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{1}{1 + e^\theta} + \frac{1}{1 + e^\theta}\frac{d e^\theta}{d\theta}
$$

Solve the final expression for the answer you want

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is as such:
$$e^\theta = \frac{\mu}{1-\mu} \implies \frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta}=\mu$$
You can differentiate this as you wish; using the quotient rule we get
$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \frac{e^\theta}{1+e^\theta} = \frac{e^\theta(1+e^\theta) - e^{2\theta}}{(1+e^\theta)^2}$$
Feel free to clean up that last expression as you like