# Confusion about integrals.

Tags: integration

Lets take an equation $y=x^2$ . If we have to differentiate this, we will have to differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to the ***same*** variable(say 'x'), giving us $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$. It could also be differentiated with respect to 'y' , giving $1 = 2x {\frac {dx} {dy}}$. A little algebraic manipulation reveals that this "new" equation is *identical* to the previously obtained "new" equation.(**EDIT** : By the comments and the answer given by SchrodingersCat I have now realized that this assertion of mine is correct only in some special cases.)

So, one thing is clear : *"Differentiation of both sides of an equation is done with respect to a single variable"*.

Now here is my question : Is this applicable to integrals too?

In other words, do we have to integrate both sides of the equation with respect to a *single* variable?

If the answer is "yes" , then how is it possible to integrate an expression in one variable with respect to some other variable ? (A "Reverse Chain Rule" ???)

If the answer is "no", then please provide some concrete examples to support your answer.

I know this is a ***very*** elementary question, but still it troubles me a lot.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction, its just notation. You might want to look at something called the "inverse function theorem".

Comment: Please answer the question !!!!

Comment: I have seen various instances where $\frac {dy} {dx}$ is treated as a fraction.

Comment: [It just isn't though](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A little algebraic manipulation reveals that this "new" equation is
>   identical to the previously obtained "new" equation.

I realize the context in which you are saying this, but you are *wrong*. Your first equation gives you $\boxed{\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x}$ and your second equation gives you $1 = 2x {\frac {dx} {dy}}$ which on algebraic manipulation gives, at most, $\boxed{\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{2x}}$ AND they are **just not the same**.
Only [certain functions satisfying certain properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292590/is-frac-mathrmdx-mathrmdy-frac1-left-frac-mathrmdy) have the following relation to hold true i.e. $\large\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$ and your function $f(x)=x^2$ happens to be one of them.

---

And now for your question, the answer is NO.

Example: $\mathrm{dy}=2x \,\,\mathrm{dx} \implies \int_{y_1}^{y_2}\mathrm{dy}=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}2x \,\,\mathrm{dx} $

And $x$ and $y$ are not the same.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The link was helpful. Thanks for clearing my doubt !!! +1.

Comment: So in definite integration, not only are the "w.r.t" variable different, but the upper and lower bounds also vary according to the variables ???

Comment: Oh yes ... thats it.

Answer (score 5):

From the modern perspective, differentiation and integration act on *functions*, not on *equations*. This fact gets hidden because the most convenient way to write common functions is to use an algebraic formula that expresses the output in terms of the input.

For example, $y = f(x) = x^{2}$ commonly denotes the squaring function, while $x = g(y) = \sqrt{y}$ denotes one branch of the inverse of $f$. (In each equation, $x$ and $y$ are *dummy variables*; one could write $y = g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ with *identical* meaning. The benefit of writing $x = \sqrt{y}$ is that these dummy variables are (mostly) compatible with the dummy variables in $y = x^{2}$, allowing us to work both both functions "in the same [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)".)

"Differentiating $y = x^{2}$ with respect to $x$, obtaining $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$" amounts to the assertion $f'(x) = 2x$; the derivative of the squaring function is the multiplication-by-two function.

"Differentiating $y = x^{2}$ with respect to $y$, obtaining $1 = 2x\frac{dx}{dy}$" amounts to the assertion $g'(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$.

Leibniz notation blurs an important distinction, denoting a derivative *function* $f'$ and the *value of a derivative* $f'(x)$ at an arbitrary point with the same symbol, $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Inevitably this leads to confusion among students who carefully ponder the meaning of notation. The "identity"
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{dy/dx}
\tag{1a}
$$
is a perfect example. Written more carefully, the claim is that if the composition $f \circ g$ is the indentity function on some open interval $I$ and if $f$ is differentiable on $g(I)$, then
$$
g'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} = \frac{1}{f'(g(y))}
\tag{1b}
$$
for all $y$ in $I$ where $g'(f(y)) \neq 0$. While (1a) looks like manipulation of fractions, closer inspection (1b) reveals the functions $f'$ and $g'$ are not reciprocals, their values *at suitably-chosen inputs related by $f$* are reciprocals. Equation (1a) is error-prone for both interpretations of Leibniz notation.

In this same spirit, integrals are not taken "with respect to a variable". Spivak's notation, $\int_{a}^{b} f$ instead of the near-universal $\int_{a}^{b} x^{2}\, dx$ (for $f(x) = x^{2}$), explicitly acknowledges this. Unfortunately, this analogue of Newton notation for integrals is inconvenient in practice. As with derivatives, it's much easier to specify a function (and its (anti-)derivatives) by giving the value at a "generic" input $x$ and using compatibly-named dummy variables between multiple functions.

"Integrating the chain rule" (with $f$ continuous and $h'$ continuously-differentiable, say) gives
$$
\int_{h(a)}^{h(b)} f(u)\, du = \int_{a}^{b} f(h(x))\, h'(x)\, dx.
\tag{2a}
$$
This is customarily explained in calculus books by "substituting $u = h(x)$, so that $du = h'(x)\, dx$, and $u = h(a)$ when $x = a$, etc." It should be clear why calling the respective sides "the integral of $y = f(u)$ with respect to $u$" and "the integral of $y = f(u)$ with respect to $x$" would be logically inconsistent, however. The *limits of integration differ* (as SchrodingersCat notes), and the *functions being integrated are not the same*.

In "Newtonian" notation, for the record, the change of variables formula reads
$$
\int_{h(a)}^{h(b)} f = \int_{a}^{b} (f \circ h)\, h'.
\tag{2b}
$$

Comment: Your answer pinpoints the real issue. It is important to understand the notation and it's meaning carefully. I especially like your remark about equations $(1a)$ and $(1b)$. +1