# Can you calculate $\frac{dx}{dy}$ by finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and flipping it over?

Tags: calculus

This may be a silly question but for example if you had the gradient at $x=4$ of $y=x^2+1$, then can you just calculate $\frac{dx}{dy}$ by finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and flipping it over? Or must you make $x$ the subject and differentiate?

Comment: That's not a silly question at all.  It's a completely natural question.

Comment: Related: [Confusion about integrals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093374).

Comment: Be careful when you move on to multivariable calculus, though: you generally can’t do the same thing with partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is invertible and differentiable, with $f'$ never zero, then $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable and

$$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}. $$

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

implicit differentiation operator d/dy

$y = x^2 + 1$

$d/dy(y) = d/dy(x^2 + 1)$

$1 = 2x dx/dy$   (by the chain rule on the RHS)

$dy / dx = 2x$

as expected

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. If both derivatives exist, they are reciprocal, that is

$\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}=1$

Comment: Don't forget the nonzero condition since $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: That's why I said "if both derivatives exist" :)