# Counterexample to $ \frac{\mathrm{d}{y}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{\mathrm{d}{y}} \right)} $

Tags: derivatives, examples-counterexamples

I saw this question: [Is $ \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{\mathrm{d}{y}} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}{y}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} \right)} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292590/is-frac-mathrmdx-mathrmdy-frac1-left-frac-mathrmdy)

If this is true then see the following example:

$y = sin(x)$, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = cos(x)$

But also $x = sin^{-1}(y)$, so $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Therefore, clearly $\frac{dy}{dx} \neq \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$

How is this possible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Derivatives_of_inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: Let's try that on $y = f(x) = c [const]$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that $$\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d y}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\color{crimson}y^2}}$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-sin^2(x)}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{cos^2(x)}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{cos(x)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that
$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}=\frac{1}{\left|\cos x\right|}$. 
Now compare $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}$.