# If $x=ye^y$, find $\frac{dx}{dy}$, and use it to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> If $x=ye^y$, then explicit differentiation to find $\frac{dx}{dy}$, and the implicit differentiation to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ yield consistent results.

Explain if the above line is True or False. (Ans: True)

But why? When we can clearly see using [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdy%5Bye%5Ey%5D), explicit differentiation is $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = e^y \times (1 + y)$.

Implicit differentiation using [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx%3Dy%5Bx%5D%20*%20e%5E%28y%5Bx%5D%29%2C%20x%5D), is $y'(x) = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{e^y (y+1)}$

They seem clearly different, and not consistent result because they are reciprocal(?) of each other?

Comment: The answers aren't meant to be equal, they're measuring different values. The result is consistent with $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}},$ which is a pretty well-known identity.

Comment: $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$ should be reciprocal each other.

Comment: (1) So them being reciprocal is "consistent results"? /// (2) I thought consistent result means they are = each other. So it is my understanding of the question that is wrong..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions and $y = f(x) \cdot g(x)$, the derivative of the product $y$ is given by:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x) \cdot g(x)\right) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$

Thus, for $f(y) = y$ and $g(y) = e^y$, then the differentiation of $x= ye^y$ gives you:

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{d}{dy}\left(ye^y\right) = e^y + ye^y = e^y(1 + y)$$

Thus, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}} = \dfrac{1}{e^y(1 + y)}$.

Doing implicit differentiation on $x= ye^y$ with respect to $x$:

$$\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(ye^y\right) = \frac{dy}{dx}e^y + y\frac{(de^y)}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}e^y + ye^y\frac{dy}{dx} = e^y(1 + y)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\therefore \  e^y(1 + y)\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dx} = 1 \ \Rightarrow \ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{e^y(1 + y)}$$

Comment: So them being reciprocal is "consistent results"? I thought consistent result means they are = each other. So it is my understanding of the question that is wrong..?

Comment: Please look at the comment by Stephen Donovan: "The answers aren't meant to be equal, they're measuring different values. The result is consistent with $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$, which is a pretty well-known identity." I think that says everything.

Comment: I see, I just got confused by the question is seem, thank you! Why is $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$ well known, where is it used..? Is there a reason why people won't just say $frac{dx}{dy}$ instead?

Comment: It's from the chain rule. Read through [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292590/) and see if it helps.

Comment: @Toby Mak: That is a good reference. +1 for you.